# STRUCT in Big Query From another table

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery

i have some problem in BigQuery,

i have 2 tables
first tables is paymentSchedule

| ID | index_month | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 1000000 |
| aaa | 2 | 2000000 |
| bbb | 1 | 500000 |
| bbb | 2 | 2500000 |
| bbb | 3 | 2000000 |
| ccc | 1 | 2000000 |

second table is BorrowerTable

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | Alexa |
| bbb | Jorde |
| ccc | Juan |

and i want to write query using STRUCT and the result that i want is :

| ID | Name | index_month | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Alexa | 1 | 1000000 |
|  |  | 2 | 2000000 |
| bbb | Jorde | 1 | 500000 |
|  |  | 2 | 2500000 |
|  |  | 3 | 2000000 |
| ccc | Juan | 1 | 2000000 |

i already write query but it doesnt work

> select *, STRUCT[select * from paymentSchedule where
> id=BorrowerTable.ID]from BorrowerTable

Answer (score 1):

```
with paymentSchedule as (
  select 'aaa' as id, 1 as index_month, 1000000 as amount union all
  select 'aaa', 2, 2000000 union all  
  select 'bbb', 1, 500000 union all  
  select 'bbb', 2, 25000000 union all    
  select 'bbb', 3, 20000000 union all    
  select 'ccc', 1, 20000000
),
BorrowerTable as (
  select 'aaa' as id, 'Alexa' as name union all
  select 'bbb', 'Jorde' union all
  select 'ccc', 'Juan'
)
select *, array(select struct(index_month, amount) from paymentSchedule where id=BorrowerTable.ID)
from BorrowerTable
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to order by f0_.index_month desc ?

Comment: `select *, array(select struct(index_month, amount) from paymentSchedule where id=BorrowerTable.ID order by index_month desc) from BorrowerTable`

Comment: @SergeyGeron . . . I still prefer `array_agg()` in the subquery because I find it clearer, but this answer is correct and should be accepted.